Geofences with Compose BroadcastReceiver
I am trying to set up some geofences and then notice through BroadcastReceiver whenever any geofence is exit or entered. Geofence API is supposed to trigger events when moving in and out of the geofence, but is not working. Moreover, I also tried to trigger as soon as it is registered when setting my current location statically, but does not work either. I am doing it with Compose but there is no way to receive any event... my code is as follows, taking into account I already requested permissions and granted them:
Composable Receiver:
@Composable
fun GeofenceBroadcastReceiver(
    systemAction: String,
    systemEvent: (userActivity: String) -> Unit,
) {
    val TAG = "GeofenceBroadcastReceiver"
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val currentSystemOnEvent by rememberUpdatedState(systemEvent)

DisposableEffect(context, systemAction) {
    val intentFilter = IntentFilter(systemAction)
    val broadcast = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val geofencingEvent = intent?.let { GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(it) } ?: return

            if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
                val errorMessage =
                    GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(geofencingEvent.errorCode)
                Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: $errorMessage")
                return
            }

            val alertString = "Geofence Alert :" +
                    " Trigger ${geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences}" +
                    " Transition ${geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition}"
            Log.d(TAG, alertString)
            currentSystemOnEvent(alertString)
        }
    }

    ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
        context,
        broadcast,
        intentFilter,
        ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
    )

    onDispose {
        context.unregisterReceiver(broadcast)
    }
}

}
Composable Screen
@Composable
private fun GeofencingControls() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val geofenceHelper = remember { GeofenceHelper(context) }
    var geofenceTransitionEventInfo by remember { mutableStateOf(String.empty()) }

DisposableEffect(LocalLifecycleOwner.current) {
    onDispose {
        scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            geofenceHelper.unregisterGeofence()
        }
    }
}

// Register a local broadcast to receive activity transition updates
GeofenceBroadcastReceiver(systemAction = CUSTOM_INTENT_GEOFENCE) { event ->
    geofenceTransitionEventInfo = event
    Toast.makeText(context, "Geofence EVENT RECEIVED $event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
    Button(onClick = {
        geofenceHelper.addGeofence(
            "Random",
            location = Location("").apply {
                latitude = 40.375159
                longitude = 1.147349
            }
        )
    }) {
        Text(text = "New geofence to list")
    }

    Button(onClick = {
        geofenceHelper.registerGeofence {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Geofence registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }) {
        Text(text = "Register Geofence")
    }
}
}

GeofenceHelper
class GeofenceHelper(context: Context) {
    private val client = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context)
    val geofenceList = mutableMapOf<String, Geofence>()

    private val geofencingPendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(CUSTOM_INTENT_GEOFENCE)
        intent.setPackage(context.packageName)

        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            0,
            intent,
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            } else {
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            }
        )
    }

    fun addGeofence(
        key: String,
        location: Location,
        radiusInMeters: Float = 100.0f,
        expirationTimeInMillis: Long = 30 * 60 * 1000,
    ) {
        geofenceList[key] = createGeofence(key, location, radiusInMeters, expirationTimeInMillis)
    }

    fun removeGeofence(key: String) {
        geofenceList.remove(key)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun registerGeofence(onAdded: () -> Unit = {}) {
        client.addGeofences(createGeofencingRequest(), geofencingPendingIntent)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "registerGeofence: SUCCESS")
                onAdded()
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d(TAG, "registerGeofence: Failure\n$exception")
            }
    }

    suspend fun unregisterGeofence() = runCatching {
        client.removeGeofences(geofencingPendingIntent).await()
        geofenceList.clear()
    }

    private fun createGeofencingRequest(): GeofencingRequest {
        return GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
            addGeofences(geofenceList.values.toList())
            setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
        }.build()
    }

    private fun createGeofence(
        key: String,
        location: Location,
        radiusInMeters: Float,
        expirationTimeInMillis: Long,
    ): Geofence {
        return Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(key)
            .setTransitionTypes(GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .setCircularRegion(location.latitude, location.longitude, radiusInMeters)
            .setExpirationDuration(expirationTimeInMillis)
            .build()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "GeofenceHelper"

        const val CUSTOM_INTENT_GEOFENCE = "GEOFENCE-TRANSITION-INTENT-ACTION"
    }
}


Please describe in detail how you are testing (device/emulator, delay between movement, and how long of a duration at each point). From what I recall you need to stay in your geofence for quite a bit of time before it triggers (5 minutes?). My guess for the long delay is to prevent false positives if the user was bouncing in and out of geofence area due to bad location tracking.

I try with both physical device and emulator. The thing is that if you create a geofence in your current location, it should trigger automatically the EnterEvent because you are already in

You can take reference from this open source project that has geofence feature: https://github.com/canopas/group-track-android build in jetpack compose

Somewhere around here. In data module

@MeghLath but your GeofencesReceiver is not a Composable, I am trying to make it composable..
